# stream close (and using) doesn't work for a smal group of specific files! Very strange issue

Tags: vb.net, stream

I have the problem that a stream cant Close for a very small group of files.

I open the File with

```
uploadStream = File.OpenRead(localpath)
```

and close it with

```
uploadStream.Dispose()
```

For, i would say 99.99% of all files it works but there are files where the file is still open from the application after the closing.

I upload one of the files who doesn't work, a simple NFO (textfile), here:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-11726967/FALLEN.NFO.html

**Any idears, tipps or helpfull fixes?**

EDIT: Short full program how works for 99.9% of all files (but not for the uploaded one)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
  Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim testfile As String = "c:\testfile.txt"
    Dim testStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(testfile)
    Thread.Sleep(500)
    testStream.Dispose()
    File.Delete(testfile)
    'same problem with using
    'Using testStream = New FileStream(testfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    'Thread.Sleep(500)
    'End Using
    'File.Delete(testfile)
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: If you have any hope of assistance, you'll need to provide a [MCVE]

Comment: I have updatet the star post with a short complete example.

Comment: nfo?! uploading?! 10,000 of them?! I smell something... :)

Comment: not all of the files with this strange problem are NFOs :)

Comment: That´s why one should always use [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) when dealing with files, databases etc.

Comment: You see in the example that the problem is the same with using.  I can't use using in my programm because its a asynchron upload ;).

Comment: No ideas? I "fix" the problem with a cmd comand but it's a dirty patch.